# aapt no such file or directory, unable to build Android project

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to build an Android project via commandline with `./gradlew assemble`.  On my Jenkins CI on Mac OS, I have the following build setup:

- compileSdkVersion = 25
- targetSdkVersion = 25
- minSdkVersion = 16
- buildToolsVersion = "25.0.0"

Unfortunately, when invoking AAPT, I get the following build error:

> Cannot run program "android_home/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt" in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/My_App/"): error=2, No such file or directory

This is a bit confusing to me, since all the directories are actually there.  So what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, the solution was to run **aapt** from the correct directory.  The error above meant exactly what it meant: that **aapt** env path was incorrect (it was incorrectly `android_home/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt` relative to current directory).

Once I set a PATH variable for **aapt** to the correct directory, everything worked.

Comment: Sounds like the solution is to also try actually building the application on the machine you are using for Jenkins. . .before you accuse Jenkins of not being able to build the application.